# Match custom tag

Tags: regex

Could you tell me how to match a string composed by:

- some text
- something that starts with a "less than" followed by any among `cat, dog, pen  <cat>` and the greater then
- then could appear some text, or nothing, e.g `<cat> some text`
- then the closure of the same tag e.g. `<cat> some text </cat>`
- fallowed by eventually some text and other tags

So an example could be

```
some text <cat> another text </cat> <dog> </dog> other text <pen> bla bla bla </pen>
```

Comment: I don't get that bit with the `<cat>`.  Are you saying `<pen <cat>> text </pen>` should match?

Answer (score 1):

You need backtracking for that. Depending on which flavor of regex you are using, something like that might work:

```
<(cat|dog|pen)>.*<\/\1>
```

The above will work in Perl. However, YMMV depending on what tool you are using. For example, in sed, the following would work:

```
<\(cat\|dog\|pen\)>.*<\/\1>
```

As noted in a comment, the `.*` in the middle should not be greedy, otherwise it will match `<dog>blah</dog> <dog>foo</dog>` only once. How exactly to do it depends on the regex engine.

In a simple case, you don't allow *any* tags in between:

```
<(cat|dog|pen)>[^<>]*<\/\1>
```

Or, in Perl, you can make the regex non-greedy:

```
<(cat|dog|pen)>.*?<\/\1>
```

Or you can do it without backtracking, but then it is footwork:

```
 (<cat>.*?<\/cat>|<dog>.*?<\/dog>|<pen>.*?<\/pen>)
```

Comment: You should make that `.*` in the middle ungreedy.

Comment: Thanks for your answerm but if I got a string like: <pen> foo </pen> bla bal bla <dog> </pen> , your regex works even if it must fail.

Comment: is it possible to do not use backtracking ?

Comment: @SimoneDiCola well, yeah, you need to somehow *deal* with that regexp (clearly, the outer `.*` will match anything including the rest of the string). As for whether it is possible without backtracking -- yeah, why not, but not so efficient. See the edits.

Comment: I'm using this kind of parsing for an xml schema.

Comment: In that case, sorry to say, but I would *definitely* use a parser lib. What language are you using?